# Mongo Atlas Data API and working with Mongoose Schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-schema

Hi we are looking into migrating our current mongo logic which uses mongoose schemas and the driver to conduct CRUD functions. We run this on serverless functions with many microservices that connect to the db so we have been hitting many issues with connection pool max limits.

We have decided to migrate to the Data API because it would resolve our connection issues. One issue we dont understand or can find documentation on is how do we leverage mongoose schema with the data api?